# How to install .ipa file using ftp server without https?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

***is it possible to install .ipa file using ftp server. i download .ipa file into ftp server to document directory. how to install it on click event without https.***

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no since this is SafariServices which handle downloading `ipa` over the air

It is not possible to install an `ipa` over the air.
Possible solutions for OTA Installation:

- **Using Xcode**

  1. From list of available devices which connected through WiFi
  2. From `Window` > `Devices and Simulators`, Select destination device from connected devices panel, On `INSTALLED APPS` tap on **`+`** then choose ipa file.
- **Using HTTPS protocol**

  1. Share manifest plist over https protocol, Sample manifest https://gist.github.com/hramos/774468